# Error converting a numeric string to decimal places

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone help me understand why the first one does not work and the second one works

1. `SELECT CONVERT(numeric(11, 2), NULLIF('4702137480', '')) / 100.00`.
   Error Message:

   > Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 1
   > Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.
2. `SELECT CONVERT(numeric(12, 2), NULLIF('4702137480', '')) / 100.00`.
   Result 47021374.80000000

My understanding was `11, 2` meant a total of 11 and the last two are after the decimal place. As the example only has 10 digits I don't understand why it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Because `numeric(11, 2)` means 9 digits before decimal point and 2 digits after. Totally 11 digits.

Comment: ok but the figure is 10 long so after conversion its 8 before and 2 after so still not understanding why it does not work?

Comment: @Robin - it's only 8 before and 2 after when you do `/100.0`, which you're doing **after** converting the data type. The system doesn't allow for time travel.

Answer (score 1):

Because first its convert it to numeric and after that divided to 100 so `numeric(11,2)` means 9 digit and you have 10 digit it is cause of error